# Time complexity of flattening a binary tree

Tags: recursion, time-complexity, binary-tree, big-o

To flatten a binary tree, I saw one proposed solution: (I know this is not the most optimal, but im trying to figure out how to determine the upper bound for this kind of algorithm.)

```
public void flatten(TreeNode root) {
    if (root == null) return;

    TreeNode left = root.left;
    TreeNode right = root.right;

    root.left = null;

    flatten(left);
    flatten(right);

    root.right = left;
    TreeNode cur = root;
    while (cur.right != null) cur = cur.right;
    cur.right = right;
}
```

So clearly this will be at least O(n), since we need to visit every node in the tree. However, I am trying to determine how the while loop (second last line in the function) affects complexity.

I have read that this algorithm would be roughly O(nlgn) for a balanced tree, but O(n^2) for an unbalanced one. I don't know whether this is correct or not, but either way im not sure how to arrive at this.

As an example, if I had a tree that looks like

```
   1
 2   3
4 5 6 7
```

and I want to flatten it to look like

```
 1 
  2
   4
    5
     3
      6
       7
```

then I expect the amount of work done by each node to be roughly something like this, since it seems like we only need to iterate through the nodes of the left subtree:

- 1: n/2
- 2,3 : n/4
- 4,5,6,7: n/8

So I expect my overall complexity to be something like 
`n(n/2) + 2(n(n/4)) + 4(n(n/8))`

I think this would be something like

`(n^2)/2 + (2n^2)/4 + (4n^2)/8` -> `(n^2)/2 + (n^2)/2 + (n^2)/2` -> `(n^2)*(1/2 + 1/2 + 1/2)`

Obviously this is not `nlgn`, so im not sure where I messed up here.

How does this time complexity differ from an unbalanced binary tree?